# Validacion in: Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, formrequest

Estoy tratando de validar que el dato seleccionado de un select este en la tabla "categorias_condominios" y en la columna "categoria" ya que el usuario podria cambiar el codigo html, lo hago con esta regla de FormRequest :

```
'categoria_condominio' => 'in:categorias_condominios,categoria|required',
```

Y esta es la tabla donde hace la comprobación categorias_condominios :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero escoja la que escoja me da el error:

> Error! The selected categoria condominio is invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La función exists verifica si un elemento esta en un campo de la tablq indicada, sustitye `in` por `exists`